# My OneDrive folder is nested in my OneDrive folder - what should I do?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

How does this happen, and how can I fix it?  I'm scared to move files out of the inner OneDrive for fear that they'll create some kind of circular reference.  I'm scared to delete files from the inner that they might be deleted from the outer too.

[image]

Comment: You probable enabled the feature, that allows you to backup your Desktop, Documents, and Pictures to OneDrive.  Can you confirm this fact?

Comment: First thing I would do is explorer the sub-directories via **Command Prompt** or **PowerShell**. From your `%UserProfile%\OneDrive` folder, In Command Prompt, execute `dir /al /s`. In PowerShell, `gci -ad -force -Recurse | ? Attributes -match ReparsePoint`. If the **OneDrive** folder under **My Videos-Family** is a _junction_, it will be listed by these commands. If it's a junction, it can be safely deleted using the `rmdir` command.

Comment: If `%UserProfile%\OneDrive\My Videos-Family\OneDrive` (and its sub-folders), appear to be ordinary folders, you may well be dealing with nothing more than an errant copy of the **OneDrive** folder, but I would first test for mirroring/syncronization with the corresponding top-level folders with some simple file creation/deletion trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and confirmed that the outer folder had absolutely everything I wanted, then I deleted the inner folder, and had no problems.